# How to configure webpack to use 'typings-for-css-modules' loader

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, webpack

These is my best guess, but still doesn't work:

**webpack-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: "./app.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "./app-bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader'
                }
            }
        ] 
    }

};
```

When i try to load the css file from a component it fails. Here is my code:

React component Footer (for example):

```
var React = require('react');
import styles from './styles.css';
```

fails with:

> [tsl] ERROR in
>   ..\src\components\Footer\Footer.tsx(4,20)
>    TS2307: Cannot find module './styles.css'.

but `styles.css` is in the same folder then the component.

If i use require, like this:

```
const s = require('./styles.css');
```

it trys to use the `typings-for-css-modules` loader but:

> ERROR in ./src/components/Footer/styles.css Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/typings-for-css-modules-loader/lib/index.js): Error:
>   Cannot find module 'css-loader'

I am lost here. According to [typings-for-css-modules guide](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader), i should add this to webpack-config.js:

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules' }
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&sass' }
];
```

instead of using rules.
But webpack does not recognize loaders property and throws me:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:

Here my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sitets",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "sitets",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "buildts": "tsc --build",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean",
    "build": "webpack-cli app.tsx --config webpack-config.js",
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.16.4",
    "path": "~0.12.7",
    "react": "~16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "~5.3.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.5",
    "webpack": "~4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.1.2"
  }
}
```